# APPX321 SDK folder containing 'UAP.props' for 'UAP 10.0.17763.0' cannot be located

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, xaf

I want to create an upload package for the Windows Store.
The app is essentially "Hello world" for a dev express XAF Win application. I am using the Desktop Bridge.

I am following the [docs to create the upload package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-upload-file)

This created a file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage
```

And an error

```
APPX3217    SDK folder containing 'UAP.props' for 'UAP 10.0.17763.0' 
cannot be located. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187 for more information
```

When I double click the error it goes to the following code in the Targets file

```
<GetSdkPropertyValue Condition="'$(AppxPackagePipelineVersion)' == '$(UapBuildPipeline)'"
                 TargetPlatformSdkRootOverride="$(TargetPlatformSdkRootOverride)"
                 SDKIdentifier="$(SDKIdentifier)"
                 SDKVersion="$(SDKVersion)"
                 TargetPlatformIdentifier="$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)"
                 TargetPlatformMinVersion="$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)"
                 TargetPlatformVersion="$(TargetPlatformVersion)"
                 PropertyName="WindowsSdkDir"
                 VsTelemetrySession="$(VsTelemetrySession)">
```

I am targeting WIndows 10, version 1809(10.0; Build 17763) and also have this as the min version.

The application is using .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: checking https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per  [the Microsoft link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) I had to install the update for Windows 10 SDK, version 1809.

Comment: Nice information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a CI/CD project that relied on the `1703` release. I used [`choco`](https://chocolatey.org/) to fix it as a build-step.

`choco install windows-sdk-10.1 --version=10.1.15063.468`

Answer (score 0):

My Logs :

> Error APPX3217: SDK folder containing 'UAP.props' for 'UAP
> 10.0.18362.0' cannot be located.

This works for me.

1. Go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/
2. Install SDK: Windows 10 SDK, version 1903 (10.0.18362.1)
3. Then, rebuild it succeeded.